# Confusion about a step of a proof of countability of algebraic numbers.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am trying to understand the proof of the fact that The set of all algebraic numbers is a countable set. The proof I am reading is from "Theory of sets" by E.Kamke.The proof is quite similar to the proofs in some other website ([Link 1](https://www.planetmath.org/AlgebraicNumbersAreCountable)) ([Link 2](https://notesonmathematics.wordpress.com/2013/04/06/the-algebraic-numbers-are-countable/)). It starts from defining the height $h$ of a polynomial:

> $$h = n + a_n + |a_{n-1}| + ... + |a_1| + |a_0|$$

Or in the second website

> $$h = n + \sum_{i=0}^n |a_i| $$

What I dont understand is that , why do we also need $n$  ?

Comment: You need the $n$ to limit the power of the polynomial.  If we didn't have the $n$ and we defined height as $\sum |a_i|$ then $3x^2 + 2x + 1$ and $3x^3 + 2x^2 + 1$ and $x^{97} + 2x^{56} + x^{43} + 2$ would all have height $6$ and there would be an *infinite* number of polynomials with height $6$.  The proof relies and being a countable union of *finite* sets.  (Although a countable union of countable sets is countable but that would not be a direct construction)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want a finite number of polynomials, and so a finite number of algebraic numbers,  to correspond to each height.  This then makes it possible to list the algebraic numbers by height and thus show that there are a countable number of them.

If you did not have the $n$ term then the following would all have height $3$:

$$x-2=0$$
$$x^2-2=0$$
$$x^3-2=0$$
$$x^4-2=0$$
$$x^5-2=0$$
$$\cdots$$

so there would be an infinite number their roots and so of distinct algebraic numbers of height $3$ and you would not reach those of height $4$ in your list.

Comment: thanks for your response. I have another question (Hope you dont mind) , In the proof of E.Kamke , it is said that "We may suppose , moreover , without loss of generality , that $a_n$ > 0  ".But why? Is it really necessary?

Comment: If $a_n=0$ then you really have a polynomial of lower degree.  If $a_n<0$ then you can multiply all the $a_i$ by $-1$ and you get the same roots.  So you lose nothing by assuming $a_n>0$

Comment: But , is it unnecessary ?

Comment: It is probably convenient  rather than necessary. If it halves the length of the proof then it is probably a sensible approach